# How to assert two instances of JsonObject

Tags: java, junit

This is the first time I'm trying to write my JUnit tests. In my case I need to validate a JSON response from an API with my expected JSON string. Part of my code looks like this:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    String expected = "{\"b\":1}";
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.10/e/p");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"a\":1}");

    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    JsonObject actual   = readResponse(entity);
}
```

Now, you can see my expected value is a string. But, the actual value I am getting as JsonObject. Either I have to keep both into json string and assert them as json or I have to convert my actual value to JsonObject. I searched for both ways but couldn't figure out how. What/how would be the best fix for my case?

Comment: Can you tell us the complete name of the `JsonObject` class (including its package).

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the expected `JsonObject` and compare it using `assertEquals`.

```
JsonObject expected = new JsonObject();
expected.addProperty("b", 1);

assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Parameterized to run my test with a data provider. That being said the expected value will change based on the data provider. So, I cant always do like `expected.addProperty("b", 1);`

Comment: Your data provider can provide the whole JsonObject.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) library.

It allows assertions in a way you look for:

```
JsonObject actual  = readResponse(entity)
// objects are automatically serialized before comparison
assertJsonEquals("{\"b\":1}", actual);
```

but it also supports comparing two objects that represent JSON element internally:

```
JsonObject actual = new JsonObject();
actual.addProperty("test", 1);
JsonObject expected = new JsonObject();
expected.addProperty("test", 1);
assertJsonEquals(expected, actual);
```

Framework has support for both [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and support for Hamcrest matchers.